# Covariance between coordinate x and distance in a circle.

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

Let $\Omega$ be a circle of radius $r$ and let $Z$ be the random variable that measures the distance from the center of the circle to a point. Let $X$ be the random variable that given $(x,y)$ associates the value of $x$. Calculate $cov(X,Z)$.

I'm having trouble thinking in a way to relate $X$ and $Z$ in order to find $E[XY]$. What limits should I consider when integrating? What I have done so far is define $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as:
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi r^2},\;\text{for } x^2+y^2 ≤ r^2
$$
and
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0\;\text{otherwise}
$$

Because I need to find $E[X]$, $E[Z]$ and $E[XZ]$ I defined first $p_{Z}$ as:
$$
p_{Z}(t) = \frac{2x}{r^2},\;\text{for } 0<t≤r
$$
Which resulted in: $E[Z]=\frac{2}{3}r$.

Then with $p_{X,Y}$ I integrated with the limits where $x$ is inside the circle to find $p_{X}$ as follows:
$$
p_X(x) = \int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}p_{X,Y}dy = \int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}dy = \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}dy = \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\left(\sqrt{r^2-x^2} + \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right)= \frac{2}{\pi r^2}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}
$$

This left me with:
$$
E[X] = \int_{-r}^{r}xp_{X}(x)dx = \int_{-r}^{r}x\cdot\frac{2}{\pi r^2}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx = 0
$$

My main problem comes when finding $E[XZ]$. How should I define $p_{X,Z}$? I think I should be doing the double integral of $p_{X,Z}$, but how? I guess it is with establishing it as follows:
$$
\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}xtp_{X,Z}dxdt
$$
I don't know if that's the way to go, because I've seen the limits of $p_{Z}$ defined from $0$ to $r$ instead of $-r$ to $r$. Any help in defining $p_{X,Z}$, the limits of these integrals or in telling me what should I do is appreciated.

Comment: If your sample space if $\Sigma$ and $(X,Y)\sim \mathcal{U}(\Sigma)$ then $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}$ whenever $(x,y)\in \Sigma$ and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ else. It follows that $$E\Big(g(X,Y)\Big)=\int_{\Sigma}g(x,y)f_{XY}(x,y)ds$$ Can you finish? Or you mean to say thay $\Sigma$ is a *disc* of radius $r$ cenetered about the origin?

Comment: There's an easier way to answer your original question: what is $cov(-X,Z)$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think I understand the property you're telling me. But my main problem is that I don't know how to relate $X$ and $Z$ in order to define $p_{X,Z}$ and how to establish its limits of integration for finding $E[XZ]$. And yes, mi $\sum$ is a disc of radius $r$ centered in the origin, which in this case I called $\Omega$.

Comment: @1Rock Sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean by that. I don't see how I could use $cov(-X,Z)$ or even how to find it.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is a *disc* of radius $r$ then $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$ for $(x,y)\in \Sigma$ and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ elsewhere. If you're trying to compute $$\text{cov}(X,Z)=E\Big( X\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)-E(X)E\Big(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)$$ you can use the law of the unconscious statistician like I stated in my first comment to find these expectations without finding the joint pdf of $X$ and $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$

Comment: @MatthewPiling Oh, I see. So it's about defining $Z$ using the relation it has with $X$ and $Y$ in order to calculate its covariance with the law you just said. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. Once you have $Z$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$ you don't need to find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Z$ anymore and you can just use LOTUS. Also note the integral I wrote in my first comment is really a double integral now since $\Sigma$ is a $2D$ subset of the $xy-$plane.

Comment: @DancingIguana you can show that $cov(X,Z)=cov(-X,Z)$. Then you can use linearity of expectation to say $2cov(X,Z)=cov(X,Z)+cov(-X,Z)=cov(0,Z)=0$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling So, what you mean by that is that I have to consider the integrals and each one with its own integration limits, right? So it should be something like
$$
\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}p_{X,Z}dxdz
$$

Comment: @1Rock Thanks for your contribution. I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nicely written solution for your own reference.

Let $\Sigma$ be a disc of radius $R$ centered about the origin, and suppose $(X,Y)\sim \mathcal{U}(\Sigma)$. The density of $(X,Y)$, namely $f_{XY}$, has formula $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi R^2}$ for $(x,y)\in \Sigma$ and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ elsewhere. You're trying to compute $$\text{cov}(X,Z)=\mathbb{E}\Big(X\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}\Big(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)$$ From the law of the unconscious statistician, $$\mathbb{E}\Big(X\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)=\int_{-R}^R \int _{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}f_{XY}(x,y)dydx=0$$ $$\mathbb{E}\big(X\big)=\int_{-R}^R \int _{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}xf_{XY}(x,y)dydx=0$$ $$\mathbb{E}\Big(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\Big)=\int_{-R}^R \int _{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}f_{XY}(x,y)dydx=\frac{2R}{3}$$ Putting this all together we get $$\text{cov}(X,Z)=0$$

Comment: Thanks! You explained it in a really clear way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(Z,\Phi)$ be the polar analogous of $(X,Y)$. Then $\Phi\sim U(0,2\pi)$, $Z\sim \dfrac{2z}{R^2}$, and $\Phi \perp\!\!\!\perp Z$, so

$$E\{XZ\} = E\{Z^2\cos(\Phi)\} = E\{Z^2\}E\{\cos(\Phi)\} = 0$$

because $E\{\cos(\Phi)\}=0$.

Also $E\{X\}=0$, so $cov(X,Z)=0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!